# Difference between windows power shell and visual studio developer power shell

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell

I am wondering if there is any difference between the **Windows Power Shell** available in Windows 10 or 11, and the **Visual Studio Developer Power Shell** that can be opened from Visual Studio (2019 or 2022).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There should be no difference between PowerShell self (assuming that the `$PSVersionTable` is the same). But as the host is different you might see slight differences with regards to the output (e.g. `Write-Host` cmdlet), starting with the default colors. In other words, your question is very brought, do you have a specific issue related to the two hosts?